# Cannot connect to Amazon RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I've been trying to create and connect to a new DB on AWS for days. I made it publicly accessible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've done this but it can't connect:

[image]

HOST: vepo-qa-database.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com

URL: jdbc:postgresql://vepo-qa-database.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/

[image]

[image]

Why will it not connect?

[image]

Comment: What is the configuration of the Inbound rules in your Security Group attached to the database?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I just added 2 screenshots to the bottom of the question for you. If they are the wrong area I can try again.

Comment: The Inbound rule is saying "Accept all incoming connections, as long as they are coming from resources that are connected to the same (`sg-1fefe550`) security group. **Question:** From where are you trying to connect to the database -- from your own computer on the Internet, or from an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein From my own computer. From a Sql client. I need to be able to connect to it from my computer, it is not production.

Comment: Your updated rules as saying: "All port zero from any address on the Internet, and also allow port zero from My IP address". However, your database is running on Port 5432, not Port 0. Also, it is dangerous to open your database to everywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`) -- it should be restricted to address ranges that are actually required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Security Group inbound rule configuration is:

- Allow Inbound traffic on any port as long as it comes from `sg-1fefe550` (itself!)

[image: Security Group]

This means that only resources associated with that same security group can communicate with the database. Therefore, it is blocking access from your own computer on the Internet.

To enable access to the database, you should **add another Inbound rule** that permits inbound access on port `5432` (PostgreSQL) **from your own IP address**.

(I'm also not sure why you have configured the security group to permit access from 'itself'. This is not a normal way to configure security groups.)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it worked and now I already can't connect to it again. I tried to run a migration and then it stopped working but says it is still available. Any ideas why it won't connect already?

Comment: I'm confused -- you say that "it worked", but now it doesn't work? Did you change anything? It is possible that you might be on a different IP address (depending on how you connect to the Internet), so you could reconfigure the Inbound rule and choose `Source: My IP` again. It will update the IP address to your _current_ IP address.

Comment: Yeah I connected to it from my sql client DataGrip and it was all good. Then I tried to run a migration. Now I can't connect to it from DataGrip. Very sad. I just added "My IP" again and still can't connect.

Comment: Am I supposed to have an "instance" running? As I don't. It says my database is "Available" though.

Comment: What do you mean by "run a migration"? Also, when you attempt to connect, does it display an error message? And when it fails, does it fail immediately, or does it take some time (eg 10 seconds) before it fails?

Comment: I just changed my .NET project connection strings to the new database, then ran these commands in the terminal of my .NET project: `
cd vepo.datacontext && dotnet ef migrations add -s ../Vepo.Web InitialCreate`
`cd ../vepo.web && dotnet ef database update` 

It takes about 10 seconds. But the error message is just "The connection attempt failed. "

Comment: I added another image of my inbound rules at the very bottom of my question

Comment: Thanks!! I changed the port to all. It works. I can remove the 0.0.0.0/0 rule now. And my EF Core commands to migrate the database succeeded so I'm pretty sure the DB has tables but for some reason, the tables are not showing in DataGrip. Can I view the tables in AWS.

Comment: AWS does not provide an SQL Client for Amazon RDS databases. DataGrip is fine -- although you might need to 'Refresh' the hierarchy to see the latest list of tables because DataGrip tends to cache that information. Just right-click the database node and select 'Refresh'.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information in your question to be certain, but here are two suggestions:

1 - verify that the subnets for the database actually are public and that there is a route to the IGW

2 - add a rule to the inbound security group rules to allow you to connect to port 5431.  Generally you'd want to restrict this to just your IP address for a public instance.

Also, I'm not sure why you have 192.31.0.0 as part of your VPC range - that is a public IP range.